# How do you keep the password hidden when invoked during the su command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, suse

This is the first time it has happened to me where I am using the su command and it actually displays the password on the terminal and doesn't stay hidden. Here is my code snippet:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"
```

Code explanation: I am accessing a remote server and trying be root on that server to create a folder. In doing so I have to use the su command and it prompts me for the password. When I enter the password, it gets displayed and doesn't stay hidden. How do I fix that?

Comment: Is it accepting the password even though it's visible? When I attempt to do that type of command, `su` balks and says that the "standard in must be a tty".

Comment: yup it accepts the password, but it is being displayed which is not what I want

Comment: What if you do `ssh -q username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"` manually from the prompt, does it accept the password but keep it hidden in that case?

Comment: Its still displaying the password

Comment: What version and distro of Linux is at 74.11.11.11? When I attemt to do an `su` remotely, it generates an error indicating that it wants a real tty, not a remote connection, to prompt for a password.

Comment: @lurker I am using Suse Linux Enterprise 11. That IP address is a random one for the sake of posting a question here.

Comment: Yep I gathered that about your example IP. I was also just citing it as an example. :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to allocate a pseudo TTY (using the `-t` option on `ssh`):

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -t -q username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"
```

Without this, there's no "terminal" in this context and `su` is unable to disable echo of the password.

Answer (score 0):

Just like I replied to you [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679637/150314).

It's possible to keep it "hidden" from the command line:

Edit your `/etc/profile`  and paste there:

```
export SSHPASS='my_pass_here'
```

Use the `-e` argument with `sshpass` command

```sh
$ sshpass -e ssh usernmane@hosting.example 'ls -ll'
```

Another option is to save your password in a different file and use the `-f` argument:

```sh
$ sshpass -f password_filename ssh usernmane@hosting.example 'ls -la'
```

But the best solution is to follow the [@Hristo Mohamed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170548/hristo-mohamed) [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283561/150314):

> In general please AVOID using sshpass with a password.

> You can set up easily a generate ssh key just to do this job and then remove it.